How to implement the following multi-threaded variable access?
I have two tasks (TaskA and TaskB) that are executing continuously.
TaskA first checks if there is a request from TaskB, if so handles it and proceeds forward. TaskB first sends a request to TaskA and when it successfully receives it, processes it. I have the following pseudo code :
class RequestLock
{
   public volatile bool Request;
   public string Data;
}

classA
{
   public void Run(RequestLock req)
   {
       while (true)
       {
           if (req.Request)
           {
              req.Data = "something"
              req.Request = false;
           }

           this.doSomething();
       }
   }
}

classB
{
   public void Run(RequestLock req)
   {
       while (true)
       {
           req.Request = true
           while (req.Request)
           {
              sleep(10);
           }

           # access req.Data
       }
   }
}

Is there a better way to achieve this?

sleep() is always a code smell. You should use events, or similar, that one task can wait on and another one signal.

Have you looked at the BlockingCollection<T> class? It can solve most producer-consumer problems. Unless it's an assignment, and you are supposed to do everything manually (at a lower level).

Producer / consumer channels (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/channels) ? It all depends on what you're trying to achieve.

It is not at all clear what it is you actually want to do. A producer-consumer pattern, as other suggest, is often a good solution, but it really depends on what you are trying to achieve. Is req.Data used by ClassB? Does req.Data change value? When? How? How often? Perhaps you really want some variant of a timer to run code periodically?

Yes.
The code you show will not work reliably. But luckily .NET has a lot of built-in classes that help you with this task, some have already been mentioned: BlockingCollection (add items and wait for them to be processed), or ConcurrentQueue (handles a first-in-first-out queue without the need for manual locking) handle most of this for you. If you want to implement the queue manually, at least use a Semaphore or an AutoResetEvent.
